# wxpython: how to keep three wxTextCtrls having same size in flexgridsizer

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I want to use wxpython to implement a GUI that has three `wxTextCtrls` widgets, and I want to keep them having the same size when I change the size of the window

If I do nothing to these `wxTextCtrls`, it works well. But when I add many lines of contents in one of these three widgets, like the first one, it's size will be bigger than the others' when I change the size of the window. How could I keep these widgets having same size? Thanks!

(PS: I think the image of the generated GUI could explain my question better, but I can't post image. Sorry)

My code is

```
import os
import wx

class My_Gui(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        super(My_Gui, self).__init__(parent, title = title,size=(800,600))

        self.InitUI()
        self.Centre()
        self.Show()

    def InitUI(self):

        my_panel = wx.Panel(self)

        hbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        fgs = wx.FlexGridSizer(3, 2, 25, 30)

        button1 = wx.Button(my_panel, label='button1', size=(120,150))

        button2 = wx.Button(my_panel, label='button2', size=(120,150))

        button3 = wx.Button(my_panel, label='button3', size=(120,150))


        self.tc1 = wx.TextCtrl(my_panel, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE | wx.HSCROLL)
        self.tc2 = wx.TextCtrl(my_panel, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE | wx.HSCROLL)
        self.tc3 = wx.TextCtrl(my_panel, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE | wx.HSCROLL)


        fgs.AddMany([(button1),(self.tc1, 1, wx.EXPAND),  (button2), \
                  (self.tc2, 1, wx.EXPAND), (button3), (self.tc3, 1, wx.EXPAND)])

        fgs.AddGrowableRow(2, 1)
        fgs.AddGrowableRow(1, 1)
        fgs.AddGrowableRow(0, 1)
        fgs.AddGrowableCol(1, 1)

        hbox.Add(fgs, proportion=1, flag=wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, border=40)
        my_panel.SetSizer(hbox)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    My_Gui(None, title='Example')
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since wxWidgets 2.5.0, wxFlexGridSizer can also size items equally in one direction but unequally ("flexibly") in the other. If the sizer is only flexible in one direction (this can be changed using SetFlexibleDirection), it needs to be decided how the sizer should grow in the other ("non-flexible") direction in order to fill the available space. The SetNonFlexibleGrowMode method serves this purpose. (from: [docs.wxwidgets.org](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8/wx_wxflexgridsizer.html))

So change:

```
fgs.SetFlexibleDirection( wx.BOTH )
```

Into:

```
fgs.SetFlexibleDirection( wx.HORIZONTAL )
fgs.SetNonFlexibleGrowMode( wx.FLEX_GROWMODE_ALL )
```

The only problem I see here is that the largest minimal size of the `TextCtrl`s is applied to all the `TextCtrl`s.

Comment: Hi @bouke, thanks for your reply. I use `wx.aui` now, and it works for me.

Comment: @mitchelllc please upvote/accept to show your appreciation of my time